# Laravel ServiceProvider boot called 10 times per pageload

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-7

I try to use some code on all pages of my website. That for I'm using the boot function of the ServiceProvider. In this code I count how often ads are delivered to the user. By doing this, i realised that on some pages of my website the boot function is called 10 times. What would be the solution here to call the code in my boot function only one time per page view? From my understanding Ajax can trigger these additionall calls of boot?!

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{  
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); 

    // Load toppagetext ad
    $toppagetext = TextAdvertise::where('type_id', '=', 1)
        ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->where('active', '=', 1)
        ->inRandomOrder()->first();
    // Add up seen count for toppagetext ad
    $toppagetext->seen++;
    $toppagetext->save();
    View::share('toppagetext',$toppagetext);
 }  
}
```

Comment: Every request calls the boot. So yes, your ajax calls will trigger this too

Comment: Is there a solution to detect only the first call of a page to run the code only 1 time for all pages?

Comment: You can use middleware to do that. in that case you can run the code on the routes or route groups where you define the middleware

Comment: I just tried to use my code in a middleware and the same result. The middleware code is called 10 times.

Comment: The middleware will only be called on the routes you add it to. So if your Ajax routes don't use the middleware, it will not be triggered.

Comment: I have like 100 routes, the point is to have a solution that can be used for all routes but checks if it's the first page call. That would be the easiest solution if that was possible.

Comment: If your routes are organized it will only be a matter of adding route groups. And your ajax calls would be in a separate route file.

Comment: If you pass in the request object to that class or method (or can access it somehow), you can do something like `if ($request->ajax() === false) {  ...your counter code  }` to make sure the code isn't triggered on ajax requests

Comment: I just tried the ajax check, but the code is still called 10 times. What other requests than ajax could trigger this?

Comment: Check the network tab in the browsers developer tools. if you have resources that don't exist they will open a 404, that could trigger the code too.  (just one example)

Comment: Have you debugged the ajax check to make sure it works?

Comment: I found the problem. It's not the ajax calls, its 404 errors as Gert mentioned. I have a few images that don't exist on my local version. How would I filter this, in case this happens on my live website?